# Deploy artifacts to Nexus with multiple versions (like Docker images)

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

With Docker you deploy one image under several more or less volatile tags, e.g.:

- hash
- v1
- v1.1
- v1.1.1
- latest

Is this possible and conceivable for artifacts in a Nexus repository (at least BUILD123 and latest-SNAPSHOT)?

We are providing services other teams are using. Some consumers of this services want to develop against a latest-and-greats version of this service, some others want to develop against a certain build of this service.

Of course we could change the artifact version in the pom.xmls, create Git-Tags for this and build these tags, but this information has no value in the Git repository.

The idea is Jenkins checking out the development branch, building it and pushing it to the nexus repository with a SNAPSHOT version as well as a distinct build version, so consumer can decide wether or not to develop against a fixed build or not.
Is this possible with only 1 deployment resulting in 1 file in the nexus repository (just like Docker)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At current time this is not possible. We have some plans for the future with tagging, but nothing concrete as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hack something together on the client side that essentially builds things multiple times and then deploys multiple times with different versions. But imho you are trying to hack around instead of really cutting releases treating them as such and really having a SNAPSHOT dev version.